# Any idea how can I keep file between postback calls?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-io

Here is ASP.NET code:

```
    <div class="row1" style="padding: 3px">
      <asp:Button Text="Select" ID="btnDescColumn" runat="server" OnClick="SetDescPoint" CausesValidation="False"/>

      <input type="file" accept="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-excel" id="fileSelect" runat="server" class="hidden" />
      <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Load" OnClick="LoadFile" class="hidden" CausesValidation="False" />
      <input type="button" id="triggerUpload" name="name" value="Select File" />
    </div>
```

Here the view:

[image]

Here is JQuery code:

```
    $('#triggerUpload').click(function () {
        $('#<%=fileSelect.ClientID%>').trigger('click');
    });

    $('#<%=fileSelect.ClientID%>').change(function () {
        $('#<%=btnUpload.ClientID%>').trigger('click');
    });
```

When `Select File` button clicked dialog window opens and user select file.
After the file selected, this JQuery code fired:

```
    $('#<%=fileSelect.ClientID%>').change(function () {
        $('#<%=btnUpload.ClientID%>').trigger('click');
    });
```

and the JQuery row above trigger this asp button control:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Load" OnClick="LoadFile" class="hidden" CausesValidation="False" />
```

which is fire this code behind method:

```
    protected void LoadFile(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files[fileSelect.Name];
        int fileSize = file.ContentLength;
        byte[] fileByteArray = new byte[fileSize];
        file.InputStream.Read(fileByteArray, 0, fileSize);
    }
```

After the postBack `Process` button clicked and this code behind is fired:

```
    protected void SetDescPoint(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(fileSelect.Value != string.Empty)
        {
           //make some process...
        } 
   }
```

But the `fileSelect` control is empty.

As I understand `input file` not keep the file between postback calls.

I need to access the file in SetDescPoint code behind.

Any idea how can I keep file between postback calls?

Answer (score 0):

When you `uploading a file in asp.net` .. you must do a `full post-back` .. which can only achieve by `submitting the page (button click)`.. `no jquery trick will work` .. even if your `postback button is under a updatepanel` .. then also you `will not get the physical file in server side`

Comment: I implement full postback.But I need to access file after second post back

Comment: Browser will not send the file in next postback

Comment: It's quiet impossible because after full postback `server` send response to `browser` and the `dom` reload by response from server .. and obisouly server did not send the file back to browser .. so it's protocols ...

Comment: is there any another solution to access file after postback?

Comment: Why don't you keeping file in first post back?

Comment: I need to read the file content and then display specific data to user.After data displayed User have to select from it specific items and post it back to server after this posback I need to read file again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105262/discussion-between-moumit-and-michael).

Comment: Please don't use `inline code` for emphasis, it makes your posts unreadable.